# reference does not return expected method

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli

I have created a myCppEngine.dll in c++ with a cli header so that I can call it from my c# project.
Everything was peachy when I first created the c# project, referenced the dll and got the expected result from myCppEngine.GetLinesAAA().

Then some changes was made in the c++ but nothing that the c#-project interacts with. So I rebuild the dll and replace the old myCppEngine.dll with the new one in my c# project. Rebuild the c# project and there are no complaints from VisualStudio but the result I get looks like what would expect myCppEngine.GetLinesBBB() and not GetLinesBBB(). IntelliSense shows me that there is a method called GetLinesBBB() and there is no complaints when compiling, but I cannot run it - looks like the method does not exist.
Both projects are built on the same machine but in different solutions.

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your probably not referencing the right file. Check you reference from the C# project

Comment: My first thought was: of course I am referencing the right file! But just to be sure I changed all instances on my machine to the same version.. and it now works!
I am still confused as to why VS would use a different file than the one I have asked it to use?